# Can't access to Nifi Ui

Tags: docker, apache-nifi

I'm trying to use Nifi UI using docker on a Mac M2.

The Docker command used is:

`docker run --net=host --platform=linux/arm64 --name nifi -p 8080:8080 -e SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_USERNAME=admin -e SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD=ctsBtRBKHRAx69EqUghvvgEvjnaLjFEB -e NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=172.20.0.1 -d apache/nifi:latest`

It runs normally, as shown in the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoDiU.png)

In one of the lines from docker log I've found this:

`o.a.nifi.web.server.HostHeaderHandler Determined 11 valid hostnames and IP addresses for incoming headers: 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1:8443, localhost, localhost:8443, [::1], [::1]:8443, docker-desktop, docker-desktop:8443, 192.168.65.4, 192.168.65.4:8443,`

I tried accessing the UI through https://localhost:8080/nifi and http://localhost:8080/nifi and https://localhost:8443/nifi and http://localhost:8443/nifi but without success.

I've ran out of options about what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to access the Nifi UI using https://127.0.0.1:8443/nifi/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).